# Can For loops be dynamic in that the limits change as the code is run?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a forecasting model for a fleet of equipment using Excel wholly written with VBA.

While forecasting the utilisation of equipment, some equipment will reach its replacement threshold and a new piece of equipment takes over from there. This will require a new row added to the table for the new equipment.

I would have thought that a For loop would be dynamic, so using a variable for the upper limit would be re-evaluated on every loop, but this seems not to be the case.

I set up a simple scenario to test as per the code below, starting with 2 listrows in the table.

```
Sub Test1()

    Set Table1 = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1")
    x = Table1.ListRows.Count

    For i = 1 To x

        Set NewRow = Table1.ListRows.Add
        x = Table1.ListRows.Count
        NewRow.Range(1, 1) = x

    Next i

End Sub
```

I assumed it would run infinitely but it will only run as per the initial case provided.

Is using a different type of loop (Do While or Do Until) the **ONLY** way to achieve a genuinely dynamic outcome?

Comment: Why not use a simple while loop? And: you can answer your question yourself: just test it 

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't specific enough in what I was after. I've got the workaround in place but wasn't previously aware this is a constraint of using a for loop. Is this common knowledge?

Comment: For this, I have only one advise: rtfm. And to answer your added question: you could also do recursion if you really liked to

Comment: I'm not trying to be a smart ass, just trying to understand... but the manual says "TIP: Changing the value of counter while inside a loop can make it more difficult to read and debug your code." Honestly would have thought meant it was possible for it to be dynamic.

Comment: A For loop should never modify the counter inside the loop - that's just a basic tenet for using that type of loop - OK to exit the loop using Exit For but that's about it.  As @Psi notes - there are other types of loop you can use if you want a different behavior.

Comment: But if you tried, and it didn't work, you have your answer: it's prohibited artificially ;) in some other languages you might be allowed to do so. In C, you can do it. But it's strongly discouraged

Comment: Cheers for the feedback Psi and Tim

Comment: @Psi First, thanks for your answer, as I had the same question (I suspected what the answer would be, just needed to be sure). Secondly, Josh had a good point, since nowhere in the Micro$oft pages regarding the For..Next statement is specifically stated that the End value is static and doesn't get re-evaluated on each loop. Your advice was spot on in a general sense, it's just that the (recently?) shortened pages at M$ provide insufficient - and often confusing - information on various topics. It's like the time one takes to read the page is more important than the info written - stupid choice

Comment: Yes, my answer was focused on a sufficient solution rather than the technical possibility in that particular case. However, as you can see from the comments, nobody stops you from just trying it out. And that's in general always the best way to really figure out what's going on. I know lots of examples where the documentations says it the one way and the implementation actually behaves the other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum things in the comments to your question up:

Modifying the target of a for-loop might be prohibited in Viual Basic. There are other languages out there that in principle allow for this kind of operation, however, it's not a good programming style.

The reason is, that a for-loop is a loop counting over a fixed interval (that should not change during the loop's execution).

Instead of using a for-loop here, one may consider using a while-loop:

```
i = 1
While i <= x 
     Set NewRow = Table1.ListRows.Add
     x = Table1.ListRows.Count
     NewRow.Range(1, 1) = x
     i = i+1
Wend
```

**Caution:**
This loop will run forever (or rather: until you reach a maximum of resources, in which case it will crash). The reason is, that you move the upper bound for the iteration 1 unit further away while approaching it by 1 unit.

The best way to approach what you actually want to achieve is using a buffer list:

- Identify the items you want to create a new row for
- Insert that row into a second list
- Iterate over the second list and append the items to the original list

This way, you avoid testing the newly inserted items (which most likely won't be outdated by now).